# How in larastan to catch error having same methods in one component using?

Tags: laravel, phpstan

In laravel 10 app with larastan 2.6 in some components definition
some by mistake I have same methods used, like “label” below :

```
  TextInput::make('status_label')->label('Status 2')->lazy()
->label('status'),
```

If there is a way to catch this error ?